# ¿Como se puede corregir este mensaje de error "Can´t create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"?

Tags: java, android, hilos

A través de Android Studio estoy tratando de hacer una pequeña APP para mi celular, sin embargo cuando le hago un debuger me sale un error, me podrían indicar como corregirlo por favor

Les agradecería mucho su colaboración, ya que llevo un buen tiempo sin poderlo solucionar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por responder

Mi caso es el siguiente:

1. Tengo un activity principal (MainActivity) donde tengo un par de botones (button_1, button_2) y un par de textview (TextView_latitud, TextView_longitud)
2. Tengo una Clase llamada nuevo_hilo (código que aparece abajo) en este hilo independiente del principal busco capturar cada 30 segundos de manera permanente la longitud y latitud que entregue el GPS del teléfono. (La idea más adelante, cuando pase el problema que tengo en este momento, es llevar los valores de las coordenadas que se generan, a un base de datos)
3. Cuando oprimo el button_1 existente en el MainActivity, el nuevo hilo se activa y empieza a funcionar sin problema.

**Cual es el problema en este momento con el codigo que tengo :**

1. Cuando el nuevo_hilo empieza a correr luego de oprimir el button_1, no se bloquea y hace el ciclo cada 30 segundos, pero no me genera las coordenadas.
2. Revisando a través de un debugger en Android Studio al proyecto, encontré que hay un error (imagen de arriba). Cuando se hace el ciclo cada 30 segundos, no se va por el TRY donde se generan las coordenadas, sino por el CATCH, generando la excepción.
3. No se como llevar las coordenadas que se generan en el nuevo hilo a los TextView del MainACtivity inicialmente y cada vez que van cambiando.

Me podria por favor decir, cual es el error y cómo corregir el problema del punto uno y como solucionar el segundo.

**Gracias por su tiempo y colaboración**

Este es el código del nuevo_hilo donde trato de capturar las coordenadas, este codigo lo e ido haciendo con lo poquito que entiendo hasta ahora

```
public class nuevo_hilo extends Service implements LocationListener {

private Thread workerThread = null; 
private Context thisContext=this; 

Location location; 
LocationManager locationManager; 
double latitude, longitude, lat, lon; 

public nuevo_hilo() { 

lat = 0.0; 
lon = 0.0;

} 

@Override 
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) { 
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId); 

    if(workerThread == null || !workerThread.isAlive()){
       workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){ 
         public void run(){ 

        for (int i = 1; i>=0; i++){ 

         try{ Thread.sleep( 30000 ); 

           if ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisContext,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { 

           } 

           try { 

                LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)thisContext.getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE ); 
                boolean isGPSEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ); 

                if (isGPSEnabled) { 
                     lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 10, (LocationListener) thisContext); 
                     Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); 
                } 
  
            }catch (Exception e) { 
         
               e.printStackTrace(); // **siempre se va por esta excepción**

            } 
            
            
            }catch (Exception e){

               e.printStackTrace(); 

            } 

            }

            } 

            }); 
           
            workerThread.start(); 

            }
           
            return START_STICKY; 
           
            }
           
            }
```

Comment: A parte del mensaje de error debes poner tu codigo

Comment: Que estas realizando, agrega el còdigo

Comment: @Jorgesys  gracias por su atención, ya coloque el código y la duda que tengo, le agradecería mucho si me puede colaborar. gracias

Comment: @Japv gracias por su atención, ya coloque el código y la duda que tengo, le agradecería mucho si me puede colaborar. gracias

Comment: Gracias @Isabel agregué una respuesta, saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys Mil gracias, ya me funciono, te puedo hacer dos preguntas adicionales del mismo tema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro de  `run()` de tu Thread llama `Looper.prepare()` y al final `Looper.loop();` :

```
public void run() {
    Looper.prepare();
    ...
    ...
    Looper.loop();
}
```

Se llama `Looper.prepare()` en el hilo y luego a `Looper.loop()` para que procese los mensajes.